# Tensor product of $C^*$- algebras

Tags: operator-theory, homological-algebra, tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

We know from the paper of Douglas and Howe ([enter link description here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1971-158-01/S0002-9947-1971-0288591-1/S0002-9947-1971-0288591-1.pdf)) that the commutator ideal $\mathcal{I}$ of $\mathcal{A}(C(T^2))$, the $C^*$-algebra generated by Toeplitz operators with continuous symbol in the torus $T^2$ is the subspace spanned by $\mathcal{A}(C(T))\otimes \mathcal{K}$ and $\mathcal{K}\otimes \mathcal{A}(C(T))$. Here $\mathcal{A}(C(T))$ is the $C^*$-algebra generated by Toeplitz operators with continuous symbol in the circle $T$ and $\mathcal{K}$ is the ideal of compact operators in the Hardy space on the circle, $H^2(T)$. How can we obtain that the quotient space $\mathcal{I}/(\mathcal{K}\otimes \mathcal{K})$ is $C(T\times \{0,1\})\otimes \mathcal{K}$?

All tensor product is algebraic.

This result is written in the introdunction part of the paper of Curto and Muhly ([enter link description here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002212368590062X)) and they say that it is obtained by the paper of Douglas and Howe.

By the way, what are the nice references on the tensor product of $C^*$- algebra?